# "Computer does not meet the minimum requirements..." error when installing video driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, eeebox

I am attempting to install the video driver for an Asus EB1036 that was downgraded from Windows 8 64-bit to Windows 7 64-bit.

[image]

All other drivers installed successfully but the video driver installer (which looks like it should work as the hardware matches the name in the PCI database) gives the following error:

[image]

The CPU is 64-bit and the driver (from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&FamilyId=39&ProductID=3723&ProdId=3723)) is also 64-bit.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: Is your CPU 64 bit? Is your video card driver for 64 bit windows? Just checking

Comment: The CPU is 64-bit (it would have to be as I downgraded from Windows 8 64-bit!) The new video card driver is also the 64-bit version. I am updating my answer with more information.

Comment: There are 2 versions of the driver available on that page. Are you using version 15.36.7.64.3960 (10.18.10.3960) or version 15.36.14.64.4080 (10.18.10.4080)?

Comment: I have the same problem with both versions unfortunately. I vaguely remember that I got around this error last time by extracting the contents of the executable and manually installing the driver the last time I last had to do this. I'll try that again today and post an update.